# C++ Magic Square from txt: Only reads first square

Tags: c++, c++11

This is related to another question I've asked, but now I've gotten a little farther. I am trying to create a [Magic Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) program based on a text file input. The program will read the first square but then prints out gibberish for the rest of them. Where there is an individual number, it's supposed to set the parameters for the square following it. 
So here's an example from the text file:

```
3      <- this indicates the rows&columns
4 9 2  <- row 1
3 5 7  <- row 2
8 1 6  <- row 3
5      <- start of next square. rows&columns
17 24 1 8 15
23 5 7 14 16
4 6 13 20 22
10 12 19 21 3
11 18 25 2 9
7
30 39 48 1 10 19 28
38 47 7 9 18 27 29
46 6 8 17 26 35 37
5 14 16 25 34 36 45
13 15 24 33 42 44 4
21 23 32 41 43 3 12
22 31 40 49 2 11 20
```

Here's the program that I have so far.
I'm trying to follow the assignment instructions, which is why I have 2d arrays and functions set up the way I do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;

void readSquare(int, int[][SIZE]);
void printSquare(int, int[][SIZE]);
bool checkMagic(int, int[][SIZE]);
int sumRow(int, int, int[][SIZE]);
int sumColumn(int, int, int[][SIZE]);
int sumDiagonal1(int, int[][SIZE]);
int sumDiagonal2(int, int[][SIZE]);

int main()
{
    int n;
    int square[SIZE][SIZE];
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("Prog2Input.txt");

    while (inputFile >> n)
    {
        readSquare(n, square);
        printSquare(n, square);
        if (checkMagic(n, square))
        {
            cout << "Magic Square" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "NOT Magic Square" << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void readSquare(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    ifstream inf("Prog2Input.txt");
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
            inf >> x;
            square[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
}

void printSquare(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << square[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
bool checkMagic(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int total = ((1 + n*n) / 2)*n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (sumRow(i, n, square) != total) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        if (sumColumn(i, n, square) != total) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (sumDiagonal1(n, square) != total) {
        return false;
    }
    if (sumDiagonal2(n, square) != total) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int sumRow(int row, int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += square[row][i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumColumn(int col, int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += square[i][col];
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumDiagonal1(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += square[i][i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumDiagonal2(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += square[i][(n - i) - 1];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through your program with a debugger?

Comment: It looks like you are reopening your input file in `readSquare`.  You need to pass in the already opened `fstream` into this function.

Comment: @AnonMail In debug it looks like it's grabbing the 4 after the 3 instead of grabbing the 5 which indicates the parameters of the next square. All the functions are set up according to the instructions, so I can't pass another fstream as a parm to the `readSquare` function. It is supposed to be `void readSquare(n, square)`

Comment: @SleuthEye I'm not sure what you mean (new to this). I can't return n since the function `readSquare` is supposed to be void per the instructions. But I thought I was passing n to `readSquare`?

Comment: @SleuthEye how do I do that? As of now, I removed the `inf >> n` from `readSquare` but it's now reading `n` as the first number of the square (which is wrong)

Comment: there is no `inf >> m`? I'll edit the code above to show you what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

All, I appreciate your help in trying to resolve this. I took your comments in combination with my professors to make the below code. This will process an unknown number of magic square matrices specified by an initial size integer. 
**Sample text file first:**

```
3      <- this indicates the rows&columns
4 9 2  <- row 1
3 5 7  <- row 2
8 1 6  <- row 3
5      <- start of next square. rows&columns
17 24 1 8 15
23 5 7 14 16
4 6 13 20 22
10 12 19 21 3
11 18 25 2 9
7
30 39 48 1 10 19 28
38 47 7 9 18 27 29
46 6 8 17 26 35 37
5 14 16 25 34 36 45
13 15 24 33 42 44 4
21 23 32 41 43 3 12
22 31 40 49 2 11 20
```

**Now the final product of the code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;
ifstream inf;

void readSquare(int, int[][SIZE]);
void printSquare(int, int[][SIZE]);
bool checkMagic(int, int[][SIZE]);
int sumRow(int, int, int[][SIZE]);
int sumColumn(int, int, int[][SIZE]);
int sumDiagonal1(int, int[][SIZE]);
int sumDiagonal2(int, int[][SIZE]);

int main()
{
    int n;
    int square[SIZE][SIZE];
    inf.open("Prog2Input.txt");

    while (inf >> n)
    {
        cout << "Matrix Size: " << n << endl;
        readSquare(n, square);
        printSquare(n, square);
        if (checkMagic(n, square))
        {
            cout << "Magic Square" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "NOT Magic Square" << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void readSquare(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
            inf >> x;
            square[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
}

void printSquare(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << square[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
bool checkMagic(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int total = ((1 + n*n) / 2)*n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (sumRow(i, n, square) != total) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        if (sumColumn(i, n, square) != total) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (sumDiagonal1(n, square) != total) {
        return false;
    }
    if (sumDiagonal2(n, square) != total) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int sumRow(int row, int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += square[row][i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumColumn(int col, int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += square[i][col];
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumDiagonal1(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += square[i][i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumDiagonal2(int n, int square[][SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += square[i][(n - i) - 1];
    }
    return sum;
}
```